# How do i make an table with javascript and add table cells to it?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make the function be able to write all of the information in the array to `felt`, on the click of `button`. What am i doing wrong, how i can make this work:

```js
var search = document.getElementById("search");
var felt = document.getElementById("felt");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var personer = [{
  name: "Ole",
  age: 22,
  intrests: ["Swim", "Game"]
}, {
  name: "Jakob",
  age: 30,
  intrests: ["Dance", "Game", "Eat"]
}];

function ppl(x, f) {
  f.innerHTML = ``;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    f.innerHTML += `<table border="1px"><tr id="t${(3*i)+1}"><td>Name</td></tr><tr id="t${(3*i)+2}"><td>Age</td></tr><tr id="t${(3*i)+3}"><td>Intrests</td></tr></table>`;
    var table = document.getElementById(`t${(3*i)+1}`);
    var table2 = document.getElementById(`t${(3*i)+2}`);
    var table3 = document.getElementById(`t${(3*i)+3}`);
    var storeFor = i;
    for (var y = 0; y < x[i].name.lenght; y++) {
      table += `<th>${x[storeFor].name[y]}</th>`;
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < x[i].age.lenght; j++) {
      table2 += `<td>${x[storeFor].age[j]}</td>`;
    }
    for (var o = 0; o < x[i].intrests.lenght; o++) {
      table3 += `<td>${x[storeFor].intrests[o]}</td>`;
    }
    f.innerHTML += `<br><br><br><br>`;
  }
}

button.onclick = function() {
  var sValue = search.value;
  if (20 <= sValue && sValue <= 25) {
    ppl(personer, felt);
  } else {
    felt.innerHTML = ``;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="search">
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Search">
</form>
<div id="felt">

</div>
```

Comment: how is it that you want the information printed out? Your code's a bit hard to follow.

Comment: add and example of the expected output

Comment: i want a table and table-rows to be made and then refer back to the IDs on the table rows, so i can add table cells with the information on it.

Comment: @Blank right, but your markup suggests rather odd choices. for instance `<th>${x[storeFor].name[y]}</th>` why is this a table header? I'm not sure what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: @zfrisch atm it looks like this: https://gyazo.com/ae2fd05695fd6e6916d5f9781d79f56a and th is wrong sorry for that

Comment: @Blank to say it differently: it's a very good thing that you've posted the code you've tried. I certainly don't want to dissuade you of the value of doing that. But sometimes your code is so off-base that it can't be easily salvaged. That may or may not be the case here, but we ask for sample input and output because it's often easier to solve your problem from scratch than read beginner code.

Comment: @JaredSmith First i feed function with the array and where to write it. Second i want it to output the arrays information in an table. Is that what you ment?

Comment: Yes, and your input is fine, but it isn't terribly clear what structure you want the resulting table to have, or why you're mixing `innerHTML` with DOM manipulation, or what all the crazy interpolated IDs are or what relevance they have to this. The act of reducing it to a minimal test case will usually let you solve your own problem, and even if it doesn't will help us solve it.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use innerHTML instead of adding text string to the table. This is for the reason that table variables contain DOM elements and cannot be appended with template literals just like that.

```
for (var y = 0; y < x[i].name.length; y++) {
    table.innerHTML += '<th>' + x[storeFor].name[y] + '</th>';
}
// remove the for loop here; not sure why you are checking the length here; the age is a number and hence .length property will not work for number
table2.innerHTML += '<th>' + x[storeFor].age + '</th>';
for (var o = 0; o < x[i].intrests.length; o++) {
    table3.innerHTML += '<th>' + x[storeFor].intrests[o] + '</th>';
}
```

Fiddle for your reference: http://jsfiddle.net/69vcp1k7/

Comment: Also, the original poster misspelled "length" as "lenght", so the `for` loops never execute in the original code.

Comment: I am confused. Why does the part with the for loop with interests only work with table head and not table cell?

Comment: NVM, my bad @bcr666

Comment: @Blank You can use <td> too in place of <th> inside the loop. It works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you don't need those loops:

```
for (var y = 0; y < x[i].name.lenght; y++) {
      table += `<th>${x[storeFor].name[y]}</th>`;
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < x[i].age.lenght; j++) {
      table2 += `<td>${x[storeFor].age[j]}</td>`;
    }
    for (var o = 0; o < x[i].intrests.lenght; o++) {
      table3 += `<td>${x[storeFor].intrests[o]}</td>`;
    }
```

You need .innerHtml tho

```
var table = document.getElementById(`t${(3*i)+1}`);
    var table2 = document.getElementById(`t${(3*i)+2}`);
    var table3 = document.getElementById(`t${(3*i)+3}`);
    var storeFor = i;
    table.innerHTML += `<th>${x[storeFor].name}</th>`;
    table2.innerHTML += `<td>${x[storeFor].age}</td>`;
    table3.innerHTML += `<td>${x[storeFor].intrests}</td>`;
```

```js
var search = document.getElementById("search");
var felt = document.getElementById("felt");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var personer = [{
  name: "Ole",
  age: 22,
  intrests: ["Swim", "Game"]
}, {
  name: "Jakob",
  age: 30,
  intrests: ["Dance", "Game", "Eat"]
}];

function ppl(x, f) {
  f.innerHTML = ``;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    f.innerHTML += `<table border="1px"><tr id="t${(3*i)+1}"><td>Name</td></tr><tr id="t${(3*i)+2}"><td>Age</td></tr><tr id="t${(3*i)+3}"><td>Intrests</td></tr></table>`;
    var table = document.getElementById(`t${(3*i)+1}`);
    var table2 = document.getElementById(`t${(3*i)+2}`);
    var table3 = document.getElementById(`t${(3*i)+3}`);

    table.innerHTML += `<th>${x[i].name}</th>`;
    table2.innerHTML += `<td>${x[i].age}</td>`;
    table3.innerHTML += `<td>${x[i].intrests}</td>`;
    f.innerHTML += `<br><br><br><br>`;
  }
}

button.onclick = function() {
  var sValue = search.value;
  if (20 <= sValue && sValue <= 25) {
    ppl(personer, felt);
  } else {
    felt.innerHTML = ``;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="search">
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Search">
</form>
<div id="felt">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following solution

```js
const personer = [
    {
        name: 'Ole',
        age: 22,
        intrests: ['Swim', 'Game']
    }, {
        name: 'Jakob',
        age: 30,
        intrests: ['Dance', 'Game', 'Eat']
    }
];

const button = document.querySelector('#button');
const felt = document.querySelector('#felt');

button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(event) {
    const search = parseInt(document.querySelector('#search').value, 10);

    if (search >= 20 && search <= 25) {
        renderTable();

        return;
    }

    felt.innerHTML = '';
}

function renderTable() {
    const tables = personer.map(personerToTable).join('');

    felt.innerHTML = tables;
}

function personerToTable(personer) {
    return `
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>${personer.name}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td>${personer.age}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Interests</td>
                <td>${personer.intrests.join(', ')}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>`;
}
```

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
<button id="button">Search</button>

<div id="felt"></div>
```

Comment: What does querySelector do?

Comment: @Blank query selector grabs elements from the page using css selectors. a.e if you have a div with an id of "mydiv" you can use `document.querySelector("#mydiv")`

Comment: with querySelector and querySelectorAll you can pass css selectors as arguments. For a properly definition an examples visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll